# Unable to use dynamic credentials for ftp storage, paperclip-storage-ftp, paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to use current user's ftp credentials e.g `host`, `user`, `password` from `Configuration` table  while storing image to FTP server by using paperclip.

**Model: Image.rb**

```
belongs_to :user

has_attached_file :image, {
  storage: :ftp,
  path:  '/Images/:filename',
  url:   '/images/:style/missing.png',
  ftp_servers: [
    {
      host: 'Host',
      user: 'User_name',
      password: 'Password'
    },
  ],
  ftp_connect_timeout: 5,
  ftp_ignore_failing_connections: true,
  ftp_keep_empty_directories: true
}
```

**Model: User.rb**

```
has_many :images
has_many :configurations
```

**Model: Configuration.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

I am using this gem to upload images to ftp: https://github.com/xing/paperclip-storage-ftp

Answer (score 0):

I would make the `ftp_servers` dynamic. It looks like it's an array of json objects. You can store these objects somewhere and load them in your model. Luckily Ruby isn't compiled so every-time it accesses this model it will load the proper array.

So your user.rb would look like:

```
belongs_to :user

has_attached_file :image, {
  storage: :ftp,
  path:  '/Images/:filename',
  url:   '/images/:style/missing.png',
  ftp_servers: load_list_of_users_servers(),
  ftp_connect_timeout: 5,
  ftp_ignore_failing_connections: true,
  ftp_keep_empty_directories: true
}
```

Comment: You can store these objects somewhere and load them in your model ?
From where somewhere i am unable to use any class method in `ftp_servers` options. I have tried to use lamda expressions which paperclip support but this gem does'nt support that.
`ftp_servers: -> (attachment) {  attachment.instance.ftp_keys }`

Comment: Try with a static method?

Comment: How about trying to pass `:configuration` in that json?